# Cannot find an overload for "WriteElementString" and the argument count: "2"

Tags: powershell

I am creating an xml file and using "get-service" and attempting to grab the name and status of a running service. If I just use "get-service -name then the name of service, I will get the data I need. However, it does not write into the xml file that way. Therefore, I attempted to get-service -name "name of service" | select-object name,status. This throws the "cannot find an overload..."

Any suggestions?

I have tried to just using get-service "name of service" but what writes into the xml file is just the name of the service again. I tried to pipe select-object name,status and the error was thrown as described above.

```
# Set the File Name Create The Document
$XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("G:\TestEnvironmentScript\$env:COMPUTERNAME-State.xml", $xmlsettings)

# Write the XML Decleration and set the XSL
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
$xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'")

# Start the Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("morestuff")

 $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ServerInformation") # <-- Start <Object>

 $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ServerName",$env:COMPUTERNAME)

 $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("StateCheckTime",(Get-Date -Format G))

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Services") # <-- Start <SubOject>

$XmlWriter.WriteElementString("nameofsomeservice",(Get-Service -Name Name-of-Some-Service | Select-Object Name, Status))

    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- End <Object>

$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- End <Root> 

# End, Finalize and close the XML Document
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

I just want the xml doc to contain the name and the status. I may just be happy with the status....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'WriteElementString' error was being thrown because the data being passed by
`(Get-Service -Name Name-of-Some-Service | Select-Object Name, Status)` is like

```
Name        Status
----        ----
ServiceName Running
```

If you put the service result in a variable you can reference each element and get the desired result

```
# Set the File Name Create The Document
$XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("G:\TestEnvironmentScript\$env:COMPUTERNAME-State.xml", $xmlsettings)

# Write the XML Decleration and set the XSL
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
$xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'")

# Start the Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("morestuff")

 $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ServerInformation") # <-- Start <Object>

 $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ServerName",$env:COMPUTERNAME)

 $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("StateCheckTime",(Get-Date -Format G))

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Services") # <-- Start <SubOject>

$serviceState = (Get-Service -Name Name-of-Some-Service | Select-Object Name, Status)
$XmlWriter.WriteElementString("nameofsomeservice", ($serviceState.Name, $serviceState.Status))

    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- End <Object>

$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- End <Root> 

# End, Finalize and close the XML Document
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Makes sense now.